# Running a VM on Windows 8 without disabling Hyper V

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

I know, there is a bigger discussion about this topic, but currently I did'nt find a good solution for this issue.

First: I got a Windows 8.1 host system that uses Hyper V to run the Windows Phone 8 Emulator.

I also would like to run a virtual machine on this system (VirtualBox, VMWare, whatever works).

The solutions I know:

- Hyper V Manager to set up a virtual machine (e.g. a UNIX-system)

> > Hyper V is made for server environments, so there are no USB and sound drivers.

- The usage of bcdedit.exe to enable/disable Hyper V (+ reboot) to run other VMs than Hyper V VMs

> > I don't want to reboot my system to run a virtual machine. :/

Maybe someone else has a good idea for me. Some ideas I have in mind is to run the Windows Phone Emulator without Hyper V - but this is probably not possible. Or to run a virtual machine while Hyper V is enabled, I don't need hardware virtualization in that VM, but it should be fast enough to run e.g. a browser and to play videos and some other stuff.

Do you need some more information about my pc?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this belongs to Superuser, actually

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using Windows 8.1, it does support USB redirection to VMs and also getting audio from VMs! But it has to be a "Generation 2" VM. You need to enable and install Integration Services on the VM to do this.

Here is what you will need to do:

- From Hyper-V manager, right click on your Hyper-V Host (left pane) >
  Settings > User > Enhanced Session Mode > Check option "Use Enhanced
  Session Mode"
- In the same dialog, also check option "Allow enhanced
  session mode" under "Enhanced Session Mode Policy"
- In Hyper-V manager, right click on the Vista VM and go to Settings > Management > Integration Services > Check option "Guest Services".
- Connect to VM > Action > "Insert Integration Services Setup Disk"
- Install Integration Services and Restart VM.
- When you reconnect, you will get a Connection setting dialog and you should be able to configure both USB and Audio settings from there as shown in image below:

[image]

You should be able to get Audio output from the VM on to your Guest through Virtual Machine Connection. Hope this process works for you.

Comment: Hey, thank you for helping me here. I should have mentioned that my VM as an Ubuntu system and seems probably are not that easy here. ^^ Half of the things you wrote I already did. As far as I understood from this [site](http://baudlabs.com/how-to-install-hyper-v-integration-services-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/) Linux comes with native support for Hyper-V. I followed the instructions and enabled the corresponding modules. But the "Connect to VM" feature is still not available here. :/

Comment: @FrecherxDachs: According to the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/enhanced-session-mode) Enhanced Session Mode is only available to Windows VMs.