# Hyper-V Enhanced Session Wont Work - Grayed Out

Tags: hyper-v

I have Windows 8.1 running with Hyper-V.  I have Win7 installed in a VM, very simple.  In Hyper-V settings I checked the box **Allow enhanced session mode**.  In the VM settings (with the VM OFF) I then selected **Integration Services**, and checked the **Guest Services** box (actually all boxes are checked).

Sounds pretty straight forward, right?  However, I get ***NO dialog*** when I connect to the VM!  No way to select **display**, **local resources**, nothing!  I also noticed that on the VM window, in the **View** menu there is now an "**Enhanced Session**" option, but it is GRAYED OUT!

All I am trying to do is connect a simple USB device, and from what I can tell, I did everything right.

What is the deal?  Do I need to install windows 7 in the VM only AFTER I set the VM settings?  Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Is the VM a Generation 2 VM?
I wrote about the settings that worked for me in this answer, take a look:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20234346/965588

Comment: As of 03.06.2020 and this problem is still present. Microsoft should resolve it - so many man-hours wasted for a clipboard!

Answer (score 29):

ESM only works with Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 VMs. Since you're using a Win7 VM, ESM isn't going to be available.

Comment: This is the direct answer.

Comment: I'm running a Windows Server 2012 R2 client VM on my Windows 10 host and it's also grayed out for me. -- It works fine in my Windows 8.1 VM though.  Any advice?

Comment: You mean you're running a 2012 R2 guest, right? Do you see an option to upgrade configuration for that Hyper-V instance?

Answer (score 15):

If anyone has the RemoteFX adapter added to the VM, be aware that this *disables* "enhanced session mode" for that VM.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this issue after installing Windows 10 Home as a guest OS. For Windows guests, [Hyper-V requires that RDS be enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/learn-more/use-local-resources-on-hyper-v-virtual-machine-with-vmconnect#requirements-for-using-local-resources) to support enhanced sessions, and that feature is only available in Windows 10 Pro edition or higher.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of connecting via the Hyper-V connector (Virtual Machine Connection), try using a **Remote Desktop Connection**. RDP supports sharing USB devices, audio, going full-screen (even spanning multiple monitors) and other features. Since Hyper-V runs as a background service, you don't need either the connector of the Hyper-V manager to be open. You don't even need to be logged in if you are remoting in from another workstation. I'm convinced that "enhanced mode" is just using RDP behind the scenes.

Answer (score 3):

I am now having the same problem, in ALL kinds of VM (Generation 1 or 2 does not matter), including when starting a fresh Windows 10 guest from Windows 10.

All the setting for Hyper-V server are enabled, as well as in the guest OS settings.

Creating a new VM on a new virtual disk also has the same problem. The Enhanced session is still grayed (this is true independantly that I install it in Generation 2/UEFI boot, or Generation 1/BIOS boot, or if I enable or disable the secure boot boot mode for that VM).

In a Linux VM, I see that some credentials are not detected.

It was wrkling in the past in Windows 10, but no longer works since a major Windwos 10 image was applied to the host system.

For me this is a new bug in Hyper-V hypervisor: the extra services installed on it ARE running, but are not properly setup.

I tried to look in the Event Viewer, but I see no message there saying that some credential requests are rejected by Hyper-V or in any of its services. Visibly the services are running, but not detectable from the guest.

It seems to be a bug in Microsoft VMBus implemented in the hypervisor.

Finally I tried to uninstall the Hyper-V feature (in optional features of Windows 10), reboot, then reinstall it, reboot again. And then recreating a new VM or importing the VM.

It is still not working. Something is wrong in newer versions of Windows 10.

In a new Linux VM installation, the Microsoft VMBus is detected, but probably not connected by Hyper-V to the same VMBus instance that integration services are listening in the host OS.

An effect of this: the mouse cursor is not visible in the VM sesssion, I cannot capture the mouse, and we have an immediate alert saying that video is only supported by legacy VGA software emulation.

And it's impossible to see the option (in the login session) to connect with enhanced session, there's simply NEVER any login dialog, even if the RDP agent is also running in the Hyper-V server.

As it was possible that it is in fact a new bug in the Windows 10 client itself (not properly instantiating a RDP session) rather than on Hyper-V itself, I tried to connect to the VM from another host, and here again the RDP support is not detected and I cannot capure the mouse.

Comment: Did you report this to Microsoft support?

Answer (score 2):

Enhanced session mode is indeed using RDP protocol for connection, but not via TCP/IP.

So you could use RDP, if your VM is reachable via network.

Answer (score 2):

Check that the guest is configured to require a password to logon.  If not, the guest will disallow RDP and you won't be able to use enhanced session.

This was my problem with a Windows 10 64 bit guest on Windows 10 host.

Answer (score 0):

The ESM allows you to connect using an account of ordinary domain user when you enable ordinary (nonadministrative) account access to the RDP, via GPO or adding the account(s) to the local RDP allowed Users group.
So it seems that RDP works in the background.

Answer (score -1):

As the first check when "Enhanced Session" button is grayed out, you can try logging out and logging back in in the guest OS. That enabled the "Enhanced Session" button for me a couple of times.